# Install winpcap silently

Tags: c, windows, winpcap

I want to make a C program which uses winpcap. However, I first need to install the winpcap package into my PC using the installer before I can execute my program. How do I make my program do it (perform the actions of the winpcap installer) automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried these methods yet?
http://paperlined.org/apps/wireshark/winpcap_silent_install.html

Comment: Yes. "You can do a silent install yourself" Those 3 steps work!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [WinPcap Pro](http://www.riverbed.com/us/products/cascade/winpcap_pro.php).  It allows you to use WinPcap as a DLL, not requiring installation.  Also, as far as I can gather from their website, this is the only legal way to distribute WinPcap with silent installation.

Comment: Sir, its lotsa $$$. And isnt winpcap released under an open source licence? Why is a silent installer illegal?